# Ethernet AVB driver timing when other frames are passing from the same socket

Tags: sockets, ethernet, bitbake

I have a query regarding AVB. When the stack has AVB driver and still if we send data directly through socket with out using AVB drivers, will the QOS and the timing of the AVB packets effect. More like you send some data through avb driver and some frames directly to ethernet socket. By doind this will the timing of AVB streams get effected? And can I do this or even advisable?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this, depends mostly on the stack in question. 
In most of the cases the QoS requirements are implemented with in the driver itself. When you send data through ethernet socket, if the driver have avb capabiliies only, you will get the desired precision,sync etc.  Otherwise you are sending avb packets without the getting the QoS of avb.

Comment: Yes, The device is AVB capable with the PTP and SRP implemented. The problem arises when we connect two devices by Ethernet, the both deivices shall communicate using TCP / UDP periodically. Does these messages effect the AVB messages with high priority ?